# In Oracle PL/SQL is there any way to import packages and their members?

Tags: oracle, plsql, namespaces, package

Given a package:

```
create or replace package foo as
  f1 number := 1;
end;
/
```

Instead of:

```
declare
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('f1 = ' || foo.f1);
end;
/
```

I'd like to write:

```
declare
begin
  -- pseudocode not a valid PL/SQL
  import dbms_output.*;
  import foo.*;
  put_line('f1 = ' || f1);
end;
/
```

But how to do that ?

**EDIT by Jeff:** (trying to stay in the spirit of how things are done in PL/SQL)

```
DECLARE
  PRAGMA IMPORT dbms_output AS d;
  PRAGMA IMPORT foo AS f;
BEGIN
  d.put_line('f1 = ' || f.f1);
END;
/
```

Comment: and what if another package defines a "put_line" method (or f1)?

Comment: That's a very valid point but I do believe that would have been resolved, like it has been in many other languages, if PL/SQL would have this feature.

Comment: Personally, I think that while on the surface this would be a nice feature, there is a downside in that it takes away from the self-documenting nature of specification of the entire name of a function/procedure. One of the difficult things about reading java code as a casual programmer can be figuring out where a particular function is defined.

Comment: DCookie: how about my example (edited Q)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quite simply, you can't.  Sorry, but there is no other answer!

Comment: This would be a wonderful addition to the language, I think. Quick, someone tell Bryn Llewellyn!

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can!

:) sort of...

```
declare
  procedure put_line (p in varchar2) is begin dbms_output.put_line(p); end;
  function f1 return number is begin return foo.f1; end;
begin
   put_line('f1 = ' || f1);
end;
/
```