# Alias or synonym for a package in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a system where I have split my functionality into several different packages. Currently I am calling functions and procedures using the dot notation of packagename.object

Some of my package names (due to company coding standards) are fairly long

Can I create an alias/synonym for the package to shorten my code?

ie: instead of pkge_member_utilities.CreateMember, I could create a synonym/alias 'util' for the package and then use util.CreateMember throughout my code

I have read up on the documentation for CREATE SYNONYM but it is confusing as it seems to be used against an execute immediate whereas I want to to reference the synonym in my code

Again, apologies for the vague terminology as I'm coming at this from a Java background

Many thanks for your time

Mike

Comment: seems like you are knowingly going to violate your company's coding standarts, aren't you?

Comment: @beherenow Am I? If I give the package the correct name, referring to it by an alias within code wouldn't really violate standards/best practices would it?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to name an object in compliance with a convention only to wrap it in a synonym and see the actual name only in object browser, does it? Why not just name it `util` and be done with it? ) One point of any given convention is to provide code readability - do you add anything to readability by obfuscating the actual subprogram name and basically introducing your own convention, which means "util = pkge_member_utilites", on the top of existing one? )

Comment: @beherenow - I get where you are coming from now and completely agree. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: PL/SQL [is missing import feature](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5650319/272735) available in [some other languages](http://blog.bruchez.name/2012/06/scala-tip-import-renames.html). I also think that using SQL synonyms for this is questionable at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I agree with comments above, that largely this is an effort to defeat standards. However, sometimes standards are horrible, and as long as there are suitable unit tests, in the right situation, what is the harm?

```
create or replace package long_package_name as
  function give_me_zero return number;
end;
/

create or replace package body long_package_name as
  function give_me_zero return number is begin return 0; end;
end;
/

create or replace synonym pkg for long_package_name;

-- either works the same
select long_package_name.give_me_zero from dual;
select pkg.give_me_zero from dual;
```

Comment: You ask _what is the harm?_ I ask _what is the gain?_

Comment: @user272735 - The gain? Possibly code readability. What if development manager fresh off obtaining his executive MBA decides that all packages need to be named pkg_{module#}_{customer#}, which results in a package that is for a sales order API named PKG_3498_U3450S6 instead of SALES_ORDER_API. And you have code which extensively uses PKG_3498_U3450S6. Another possible gain: what if some dillweed uses case sensitive names for package names and you want to de-case-sensitize them?

Comment: I would say the gain is where things get a bit more complicated. For example if I have a package myschema.doingSomestuff@aDBLink and it has procedures myProc1, myProc2 it would be nice to do the equivalent to Java import at the top of a package. This would mean in that package I could refer to myProc1 and myProc2 without either prefixing them with myschema.doingSomestuff@aDBLink or having to create a synonym.

Answer (score 0):

`create public synonym util for <owner>.pkge_member_utilities;`

Comment: where would I put this declaration to be able to use it within the package body?

Comment: @Mike you don't put it in a package body. synonym is a separate database object, you create it the same way you create a package